# Net.createConnection is not a function Node Js with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My project is on React js with Node Js. I'm trying to connect to DB, but ending up with error as mentioned below: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Net.createConnection is not a function**

And here is my connection code :

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'xx',
      password : 'xx',
      database : 'xx'
    });

connection.connect();
```

And here is my webpack config :

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.jsx',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: '8080',
      historyApiFallback: true
   },

   node : {
      fs: "empty", 
      tls: "empty",
      net: "empty"
   },

   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.json$/,
            use: 'json-loader'
         }
      ],
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.(jsx)?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         },
         {
            test: /\.(png|jpg)?$/,
            loader: require.resolve("file-loader")
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Please help me out with this problem, tried all the possible options from internet but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: You can't use server-side modules (like `fs`, `net`, etc) in a browser.

Comment: Then what the solution here ? How can I connect to DB with node js ?

Comment: Where is `index.js` meant to run, in the browser or in Node?

Comment: index.js will be running from browser

Comment: That means that you cannot use any of the aforementioned modules in that bundle. Instead, you need to create a separate server-side app using Node that does all that (including connecting to the database), and use some sort of method to transfer that data between server and browser.

Comment: @robertklep I think if you give this as a full answer you've got some points coming to you...